# How to use ForEach and DropDownList together. Only getting first list value?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, dropdownlistfor

I had a simple model and I had a table of parameters that a user could set,

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Discriminators)
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            @item.Name
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox(item.Name, item.Value)
        </td>
     </tr>
}
```

With this, my code works fine and gives me the expected results in my Controller,

```
public IActionResult Version(Dictionary<string, string> versions, ManageMessageId? message = null)
{
}
```

Where the dictionary contains the results...
I'm now trying to implement a Drop down list and I feel like I've tried everything and I can't get the correct results in the Controller.

Replacing the textbox with,

```
@Html.DropDownList("Options", new SelectList(item.Options))
```

Where Options is a list of possible values.  It works great on the html side... but when I submit it, the controller doesn't get the proper information.

I always get the first dropdownlist Value and a request verification token.

How do I get the entire list with the drop down list?  I've tried assigning Id's etc and I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Note the section of the [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) entitled _"Should I use tags in titles?"_.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Model.Discriminators` ?